# How to stop dummy revisions to gain reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, revisions-list

There are user revisions re-edited by other users to get back to the same code.

As far as I know, that can be used to gain reputation (until you get to +1000), and that's annoying to the user posting the question.

Is there any way to stop this? Maybe limiting edit rights for some time?

And, if someone makes a wrong edition, I suggest there should be ways to roll-back your own edition or modifying it **when you're not the user posting the question**. Ie. I cannot roll-back my own editions in other users' posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6042341/revisions)

Comment: Mmm, as far as I can see, I made a mistake that @SwDevMan81 corrected. I can't see anything frivolous in his edit?

Comment: The subsequent edit was from a user with 10k. You can only gain reputation when you have less than 2k, as you can't suggest edits anymore. I imagine the whole approval process and 6-character limit were designed for this, as well.

Comment: Then there should be ways to roll-back edition mistakes...

Comment: Isn't... just re-editing a fine way to rollback your edit mistakes? Or, better yet, the rollback option? I'm kinda confused about what you're asking about that isn't just the current edit system.

Comment: For what i know, rollback option is just available for the user posting the question, not the editing one

Comment: @Nacho nope, you can rollback to any revision at any time

Comment: Please read, then answer, i'm saying for the user that edits the question, not the user asking it. I know the user asking it has full rights...

Comment: And... yes, anyone who can edit, can rollback to any revision at any time, like Pekka stated.

Comment: not me... i cannot roll-back this ie: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6042341/revisions. Maybe you can, for your reputation

Comment: To edit posts, you need 2k reputation http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Comment: Oh, and thanks to everyone voting down without even reading the question or posting a solution! That 'speaks volumes' about you...

Comment: @Nacho voting down on meta simply means that they don't agree with your opinion and not 'bad question' like on SO. It's more agree/disagree here.

Comment: The only definition I get is "This question is unclear or not useful". Nothing talking about "disagreeing". Right now, posting an answer or simply commenting, it's WAY easier to get to a solution. A possible feature in meta, "agreements vs disagreements"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are user revisions re-edited by other users to get back to the same code.

If there are, please flag and report them. There is still a 6 character minimum to suggested edits, and minor edits should be rejected in accordance with guidelines. There's nothing wrong with multiple users editing a single post, or even a single user editing a single post multiple times, as long as the edits are substantial and positive.

> As far as I know, that can be used to gain reputation (until you get to +1000), and that's annoying to the user posting the question.

As stated above, we trust the people who are approving the edits to make sure that frivolous edits are rejected. After you get up to 2k rep, you don't gain reps from editing any more, nor would your edits need to be approved.

> Is there any way to stop this? Maybe limiting edit rights for some time?

If a certain amount of your edits are rejected in a short period of time, you'll be barred from suggesting any more edits for a week.

> And, if someone makes a wrong edition, I suggest there should be ways to roll-back your own edition or modifying it when your not the user posting the question. Ie. I cannot roll-back my own editions in other users' posts like this one

The rollback option is available to users with editing privileges and the original poster. I don't understand why you might want to enable the editor to do rollbacks, since it would make the current system more complicated, while should not see much use in practice and would only make it easier to start edit wars. If you have a genuine complaint about an edit, post a comment or flag the post.

In addition to all these, it might be a good idea to read up about how the suggested edit system works - there are two different set of rules that apply to those below and above 2k reputation. It might be a good idea to get acquainted with these before coming here and complaining about non-issues like you did [originally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/92812/revisions).

Comment: Thanks Yi Jiang.
You're right, I should've fully read the guidelines before posting this, but It wasn't the first time I saw that behavior, and this time I was completely wrong, I asume that. I still think it can be improved, Stackoverflow makes weekly or even dayly improvements, many people think it's ok the way it is... I like improvements and suggesting one and getting 4 negative votes and no objective answers disillusions me a lot. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

I don't think Pekka really needs +2 rep more. (115k already)

By the way the reputation you can get from editing is limited (see FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)).

Comment: that's perfect!

Comment: You don't get +2 rep for edits after you hit 2k and gain the full privilege. Only approved suggested edits award the +2, and you don't "suggest" them after 2k, they just happen.

Comment: still I think it's annoying for people who post questions

Comment: and to the question... if someone that has less than 2k does that... the problem is stil there

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Post was formatted without code formatted but the first revision didn't corrected the missing `em}` part in the syntax describe by the OP.

Comment: yep, you're right, but I was just using it as example, still people can do what i'm asking, i'm suggesting a roll-back on your own editions